# Compound interest problem

Tags: finance

**Question:** A sum of money becomes 16 times of itself in 2 years if compounded half yearly. How much time it will take to becomes 27 times if compounded yearly.

(A) 2 years
(B) 3 years
(C) 4 years
(D) 6 years

**My approach:-**

$$P(1+R/200)^4 =16P$$
which gives us the Rate of interest as 200% per annum **compounded semi annually**. From here I found the Effective annual rate(EAR) as $$P(1+EAR/100)= P(1+ 200/200)^2 =300 percent $$ , So now we have $$P(1+300/100)^t=27P$$, giving us $4^t=27$ => $t=log(27/4)= 2.37 years$

What the b**ook's solution does** is that it takes 200% as yearly rate and calculates as follows  , $$P(1+200/100)^t=27P$$, and gets the answer as $t=3 years$

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Why are you dividing $R$ by $200$ in your approach?

Comment: @GáborPálovics, the $2$ is to acknowledge that there are $2$ compoundings each year; the $00$ is to change percentages to fractions.

Comment: By doing the EAR stuff you've taken a step backwards in the calculation, back to a yearly quadrupling

Comment: @Fin Does the answer help? Do you think that we post answers just for fun?

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the problem, at least as it's reported here, is a bit awkward, but it sounds like they want you to take that $200\%$ interest rate that's compounded half yearly (to produce a doubling every six months) and only compound it annually, which is an annual tripling. Understood that way, it does take three years for the sum of money to become $27$ times itself.